# Gap between cursor and drawing on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've been stuck for days on a problem and I can't seem to find a solution. There is a gap between the cursor and the drawing and I don't know how to fix it. 
I've set the height/width of the canvas in the HTML instead of in the CSS file, I've tried different ways to get the cursor position and also adding/removing some pixels to correct the gap on the lineTo line but it doesn't change anything. 
For information, my canvas is located next to a map in a container with a width of 40%, I don't know if this is the problem but I don't want to change this.

```js
class Canvas {
    constructor(canvasId) {
        this.canvas = canvasId;
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.signing = false;
    }

    load() {
        this.start();
        this.draw();
        this.stop();

    }

    start() {
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
            this.signing = true;
            const rectangle = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect(e);
            this.ctx.moveTo(e.clientX - rectangle.left, e.clientY - rectangle.top);
            this.beginPath();
        });
    }
    stop() {
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            this.signing = false;
            this.ctx.beginPath();
        });
    }
    draw() {
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            if (this.signing === true) {
                this.ctx.lineWidth = '2';
                this.ctx.lineCap = "round";

                this.ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft - 65, e.clientY - this.canvas.offsetTop - 40);
                this.ctx.stroke();
            }
        });
    }
};

const signature = new Canvas(document.getElementById('to-sign'));
signature.load();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: solid; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="to-sign" class="full-width" width="620" height="160">
Non supporté sur votre navigateur
</canvas>
```

Comment: Could you provide us a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I've edited your answer and converted your code into a demo snippet. Could you edit that snippet and make it work? That would help us debug your problem.

Comment: I had troubles making it work here, I am new to JavaScript and stackoverflow...So I edited the code to make it appear and in fact it wasn't showing because of the gap. 
There surely is a problem with the way I'm collecting the mouse position but there is a gap with eveything I try.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises if you have a padding on your canvas. `getBoundingClientRect` returns the position and size of the element's *border box*. This includes the padding. See this [Introduction to the CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) and this reference of [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: From what I understood, the border on the canvas could be an issue because it adds some padding. I will keep inform myself on this if I am wrong. 
I inserted the canvas into a div and set the border there, the gap is smaller but it is still there. 
At least there is some changes, thanks for your answer !